# Precision gets lost for big number in telegraf

Tags: precision, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin, telegraf-plugins, telegraf-output-plugins

Precision gets lost for big number.
I am using tail input plugin to read file and data inside a file is in json format.
Below is the configuration

```
[inputs.tail]]
    files = ["E:/Telegraph/MSTCIVRRequestLog_*.json"]
    from_beginning = true
    name_override = "tcivrrequest"
    data_format = "json"
    json_strict = true

[[outputs.file]]
    files = ["E:/Telegraph/output.json"]
    data_format = "json"
```

Input file contains

> {"RequestId":959011990586458245}

Expected Output

> {"fields":{"RequestId":959011990586458245},"name":"tcivrrequest","tags":{},"timestamp":1632994599}

Actual Output

> {"fields":{"RequestId":959011990586458200},"name":"tcivrrequest","tags":{},"timestamp":1632994599}

Number 959011990586458245 converted into 959011990586458200(check last few digits).

Already Tried Below things but not worked

> json_string_fields = ["RequestId"]

> [[processors.converter]]
> [processors.converter.fields]
> string = [""RequestId""]"

> precision = "1s"

> json_int64_fields = ["RequestId"]

> character_encoding = "utf-8"

> json_strict = true

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this with the `json` parser as well. My suggestion would be to move to the [`json_v2`](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/parsers/json_v2) parser with a config like the following:

```
[[inputs.file]]
    files = ["metrics.json"]
    data_format = "json_v2"
    [[inputs.file.json_v2]]
        [[inputs.file.json_v2.field]]
        path = "RequestId"
        type = "int"
```

I was able to get a result as follows:

```s
file RequestId=959011990586458245i 1651181595000000000
```

The newer parser is generally more accurate and flexible for simple cases like the one you provided.

Thanks!